# JQuery - Disable artificial delay on mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, touch, delay, tap

I just found this:

> Touch devices sometimes add an artificial delay to click events, just
>   to make sure the user isn't double-tapping to zoom.

Ok, nice, now how do i disable it globally? I have no use for zoom events and double-tapping so that delay is annoying...I want it dead :)

**Update**
PS: I have tried using `energize.js` but it just didn't do the job for me.

Comment: Are you using a click event?

Comment: Use (vclick) to remove the delay. But read this before you do. http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/